# Does emacs/spacemacs support nested C++ mode embedded in Rust Macro?

Tags: emacs, macros, rust, spacemacs, rust-macros

Reference: [rust-cpp](https://github.com/mystor/rust-cpp)

Can emacs/spacemacs support nested mode in major mode? I'm used to vim and new to emacs/spacemacs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## General information

You have access to a [wiki](https://emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes) listing some solutions to run several major modes at once:

> - [mmm-mode](https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode)
> - [polymode](https://github.com/vitoshka/polymode)
> - [multi-mode](http://www.loveshack.ukfsn.org/emacs/multi-mode.el)

In your case, you will need to run 2 major modes in order to recognize C++ and Rust in the same buffer:

- `c++-mode` (available by default)
- [`rust-mode`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-mode)

## A practical example with `mmm-mode`

I suppose your Rust environment is already configured in your Emacs. The following will add `c++-mode` while the Rust major mode is running. In your Emacs configuration file, add the following snippet:

```lisp
(require 'mmm-mode)
(setq mmm-global-mode 'maybe)

(mmm-add-classes
 '((rust-cpp ; Name of the mmm class
    :submode c++-mode ; Additional major mode, here it is C++
    :front "^cpp! {[\n\r]+" ; Start tag for c++-mode
    :back "^}$"))) ; Stop tag for c++-mode

(mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'rust-mode nil 'rust-cpp)
```

In your Rust code, `c++-mode` will be activated when the following pattern is present:

```
cpp! {
    // your C++ code...
}
```

I'll let you fine-tune the regular expression since I do not know the rules of `rust-cpp` when mixing Rust and C++.